# Copy files to the newest Directory

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I, want to make a Bash Script that can see the latest made Directory and if it found the newest Directory it needs to copy files to that one.

Currently i have this code

```
    #!/bin/bash

        cd /home/test/hello
        echo "Searching, the latest made Directory!"
        ls -tl | sed -n 2p
#It is not copying yet, because i can't figure out how to let it Copy the stuff to the newest Directory
```

This piece of code is showing the newest made Directory, But i cant figure out how to make it so that it then will copy items to that Directory

So as a example.

```
./script.sh
# Searching the newest Directory
# Found out that the newest Directory is Dir-1
# Copy the files to the Directory Dir-1
-------------------------------------------------------
./script.sh
# Searching the newest Directory
# Found out that the newest Directory is Dir-2
# Copy the files to the Directory\Dir-2
-------------------------------------------------------
./script.sh
# Searching the newest Directory
# Found out that the newest Directory is Dir-3
# Copy the files to the Directory Dir-3
```

Comment: There, need to be other ways to do it easly i think..

Comment: Because i'm not that good in Bash, But just need to have this to continue a Private Project of me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to print just the name of the latest directory, so you don't need the -l option to `ls`.  This also removes the 'totals' line, so your desired output is the first line.

```
ls -t | sed -n 1p
```

Then use the `$()` ([command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html)) syntax to capture the output of your command into a variable:

```
latest=$(ls -t | sed -n 1p)
```

and then you can use that variable in your `cp` command:

```
cp file file file $latest
```

This all assumes you have no ordinary files newer than the target directory, and that your directory names have no spaces or other unusual characters in them.

It would probably be slightly faster to use the `head` command to take the first line of your `ls` output, instead of `sed`.

```
ls -t | head -1
```

Comment: If, i'm using this code "#!/bin/bash

latest=$(ls -tl | sed -n 2p)

cp -r test.txt $latest"

It is not working it is saying "cp: invalid option -- 'w'
Try `cp --help' for more information.
"

Comment: What exactly does `ls -tl | sed -n 2p` output?

Comment: If, i only do that command (not in a Bash Script) it will Display the newest made Directory Output: "drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root  4096 Aug  8 09:53 test-2
"

But, if i make a Bash script of it, it doesnt, work..

Comment: So, not just the directory name, which is what you want.  I'll update my answer when I'm in front of a Unix computer and can test it, in a couple of hours.

Comment: And, another Qeustion, how can i let de $latest variable search in an other Directory then where the Script is located as a example > I have my script in the Directory /home/test/Script/test.sh And i want that the $latest is going to search the latest made directory in /home/test/Test/...

Comment: Add the directory you want to search to the `ls` command:  `ls -t /home/test/Test` and to the `cp` command: `cp file file file /home/test/Test/$latest`